# Google Apps - legacy free edition - GMAIL - Whitelist IP

Tags: gmail, google-apps, whitelist

I am sending email via form on my website to my gmail (google apps free).

Since 3 days, gmail considers all my emails as spam and i don't receive them anymore in inbox but spam folder.

Please advise how to whitelist an IP in GMAIL for the "Google apps legacy free edition)

For the full edition a solution can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60751)

There must be a solution for the free edition, can't believe google let us stuck like this.

Additonally how could i influence the global blacklisting of the ip, any request form or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is at the free google apps a possibility to set a filter on

> gmail->settings->filter->new filter

set on the second mask the checkbox "never mark as spam"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it sounds like the emails *you're sending* are being marked as spam, correct? If so, the article you've listed would not help. This is designed for mail you're receiving and this feature is only available on Work, Edu and GOV accounts.

Regarding the blacklist you're on, there are many. You'll need to find out which ones you're on and reach out to them. This would have nothing to do with Google.

As for helping prevent your mails from going to your intended recipients Spam folders/labels (beyond getting off the blacklist), you're going to want to see if *they* can whitelist you. You might want to also look into SPF, DKIM and DMARK (linked below).

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786
https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580

Comment: see my answer. no my email is not marked as spam but the ip of my server since i use shared hosting. most email providers set priority to ip than email since ip is fixed and senders email in php mail() can be anything you want (i could even send from admin@google.com)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older thread, but had a similar issue which hopefully helps someone stumbling onto this in the future. Google Apps (legacy free) began marking emails as SPAM for senders it couldn't verify a little while ago. To prevent this, they recommended the following:

> - To ensure that Gmail can identify you:
>
>   - Use a consistent IP address to send bulk mail.
>   - Keep valid reverse DNS records for the IP address(es) from which you send mail, pointing to your domain.
>   - Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send.
> - We also recommend the following:
>
>   - Sign messages with DKIM. We do not authenticate messages signed with keys using fewer than 1024 bits.
>   - Publish an SPF record.
>   - Publish a DMARC policy.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

Rather than use my SMTP server or PHP's `mail()` function, I chose to send email through a legitimate account using Google's SMTP server. Whether you approach it this way or not is up to you. I would suggest you follow your respective language/software's guidance on configuring to do it, regardless of the path you choose.

Regardless, make sure your SPF records are valid with your DNS settings. Review the email headers for messages received from your website and check the "Received-SPF" field. I experienced Google Apps flagging emails with a softfail/hardfail as SPAM.

The reason my emails were being marked SPAM due to an improperly configured record and a duplicate SPF record following a server migration. You should have a singular SPF record, which should look something like this:

```
 v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +include:_spf.google.com -all
```

This is configured so both my web-server and Google Apps can send emails, but rejects all others. You can find more on SPF records in these links:

http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

http://www.openspf.org/

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en

I wasn't having issues sending emails without DKIM implemented, though Google certainly recommends (or has since required) it. It is certainly better than not having it. You can find more here: http://www.socketlabs.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-email-authentication-part-6/ I did not implement a DMARC policy as of this writing.

With regards to the filter solution above, this does work. However, its control is simply over the one account in which you create the filter. Thus, if you use your website to send emails to anyone other than your one account, it'll continue to be marked SPAM until they implement the filter. In short, its a fix of the symptom, not the problem.

To answer your question, Google Apps legacy free edition provides minimal control to an administrator for the purpose of white/blacklisting emails. It primarily relies at the user level. It doesn't sound like your problem is that of white/blacklisting, but rather improper configuration in relation to Google's standard.